# Let $G$ be a group and let $H_1,H_2\unlhd G$ such that $H_1\cap H_2 = \{1\}$ and $H_1H_2=G.$ Prove $G\simeq H_1\times H_2$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, direct-product

I'm having some struggles with the following exercise:

> Let $G$ be a group and let $H_1,H_2\unlhd G$ such that $H_1\cap H_2 = \{1\}$ and $H_1H_2=G.$
>
> Prove that $G\simeq H_1\times H_2$

Because $H_1H_2=G$ we can write any element $g$ of $G$ as:

$$g=h_1h_2$$

with $h_1\in H_1$ and $h_2 \in H_2$ and then I proved that this way representing elements of $G$ is unique. Then I considered the following  function:

$$f:G\longrightarrow H_1\times H_1 $$
$$g(=h_1h_2)\mapsto(h_1,h_2)$$

I already showed that $f$ is bijective but I'm having some struggle proving that $f$ is a homomorphism. How can this be proved?

Comment: If $g = h_1 h_2$ and $g' = h'_1 h'_2$ then you basically want to show that $h_2 h'_1 = h'_1 h_2$. Perhaps the commutator of $h_2$ and $h'_1$ is in the intersection $H_1 \cap H_2$, which by assumption is $\{e\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to show that if $x\in H_1$ and $y\in H_2$, then $xy=yx$.

This is equivalent to showing that $xy(yx)^{-1}=1$, so to
$$
xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=1
$$
Now note that $xyx^{-1}\in H_2$, so $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in H_2$ as well. Also $yx^{-1}y^{-1}\in H_1$, so $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in H_1$. Both statements follows from the subgroups being normal.

Since $H_1\cap H_2=\{1\}$ we have the proof.

The rest follows easily: the map $H_1\times H_2\to G$ defined by $(h_1,h_2)\mapsto h_1h_2$ is quite obviously a homomorphism, due to the above property. Prove it is an isomorphism.

Comment: I'm always surprised when associativity is the key to an argument. It's such a subtle condition.

To the OP, if it wasn't clear: $(h_1h_2h_1^{-1})h_2^{-1}\in H_2$ and $h_1(h_2h_1^{-1}h_2^{-1})\in H_1$ is the crux of this argument.